# Graphic Interface not available when running simulation

Tags: macos, omnet++

I'm getting this error when running the configure file:

> configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too
>   old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and
>   newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV
>   variable to "no" in configure.user

I've installed Qt5 and also added the path to the paths file.

My Qt version is 5.15.0 and my MacOS is Catalina (10.15.5 (19F101)).

Probably qmake is not able to build the Qt interfaces but I couldn't make it do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my OS version is 32 bits and Qt5 is 64 bits. Since some of the binaries come in the 64 bits flavor, I was not able to use it with omnet++ 5.6.

I installed omnet++ version 5.0, but the program wouldn't run.

So I went back to omnet++ 5.6 and instead of using Qt, I compiled with tcl/tk and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding for OS support bit. macOS (After High Sierra version) is only use 64bit (x86_64). If you want to know your macOS support bit information, you can execute "uname -a" command in terminal.

- i386: 32bit
- x86_64: 64bit

I hope this has been useful. :D